# jQuery path is not working

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I have downloaded a package `TinyMCE 4.0.6 jQuery package` from the [following website](http://www.tinymce.com/download/download.php)

Extracted the folder with name `TinyMCE 4.0.6 jQuery package` and placed my
HTML file inside this folder.

Now I'm trying to refer to `tinymce.min.js` file which is located at the following path

`TinyMCE 4.0.6 jQuery package\tinymce_4.0.6_jquery\tinymce\js\tinymce`, That is 
the file is inside the "tinymce" folder.

I have tried to include following paths in the src attribute:

```
src="TinyMCE 4.0.6 jQuery package\tinymce_4.0.6_jquery\tinymce\js\tinymce\tinymce.min.js"
```

But it didn't work. Do I need to add the following path or work it some other way around?

```
`C:\Users\<username>\Desktop\Email Editors\TinyMCE 4.0.6 jQuery package\tinymce_4.0.6_jquery\tinymce\js\tinymce`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure to use forward slashes (/) instead of Windows slashes (\).

If your HTML is in the `TinyMCE 4.0.6 jQuery package` directory, then you'll want to encode the JS URL relative to that, which is:

```
<script src="tinymce_4.0.6_jquery/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
```

If you want to refer to the whole path, you'll want to URL-encode (change) the spaces in the directory name with `%20`:

```
<script src="/TinyMCE%204.0.6%20jQuery%20package/tinymce_4.0.6_jquery/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your html file and js file are in the same folder just use this

```
src="tinymce.min.js"
```

Comment: Tried running `<script type= "text/javascript" src="tinymce.min.js"></script>` but it didn't work. I wonder why.

Comment: However, when I downloaded other packages and did the same, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the tinyMCE folder to your root folder and add following on your page.

```
src="/TinyMCE 4.0.6 jQuery package/tinymce_4.0.6_jquery/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"
```